# Open a dashboard activity from anywhere in android app(any activity) on left swipe

Tags: android, android-activity, layout, scroll, swipe

I have a dashboard activity . I Want this activity to open from any screen of my app (from any activity) on left swipe. I want a global gesture to listen the swipe event from apl the activities.pls give some idea

Comment: you want the screen to literally slide as the user swipes, or you want to simply launch it on a suitable left swipe?

Comment: @Mercato both ways are acceptable but i prefer sliding the screen